# Inserting column at specific position in dataframe, is not changing the the index of rest of column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, I want to insert a specific column with column name = "video" at index 0. But doing so is not changing the index of other columns as can be seen in the screenshot. I want the rest of the column index to start from 1 and so on.

```
hmp_features  = pd.DataFrame(array)
hmp_features.insert(loc=0, column='video', value=vn)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdDax.png)

Answer (score 1):

If the columns after `Video` are all integer columns

```py
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + [x+1 for x in df.columns[1:]]
# Or
df.columns = ['video'] + [x+1 for x in df.columns[1:]]
```

Comment: @sidra **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using reindex:

```
hmp_features.reindex(['video'] + hmp_features.columns.difference(['video']).tolist(), axis=1)
```

Comment: @sidra did this solution help you?